# Methods to stabilize and maintain extremely low humidity in a lab environment

Tags: experimental-physics, experimental-technique, experimental-technology, climate-science

My atomic physics lab is in a building that experiences huge swings in humidity levels during the year due to the [monsoon season](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/North_American_Monsoon)

Our building provides temperature, but not humidity control.  Using just the building temperature control results in the following lab climates:

10 months out of the year, the room is at

T $\approx 24.4 ^oC$

Relative Humidity $< 10\%$

2 months out of the year, the lab is at

T $\approx 24.4^oC$

Relative Humidity $\approx 50\%$

This season variation necessitates significant recalibration twice per year at the beginning and end of the monsoon season.  The sensitive components are mainly opto-mechanical.

The lab currently has a dehumidifier that is spec'd at 45 pints per day during the wet season.  This specification indicates how much water the unit will remove from the air in a given day when the air is saturated with water (100% relative humidity).  The problem with such a specification is that 100% relative humidity is a way different environment than 40% or 50% humidity.

On a wet day, this unit reduces the lab relative humidity by about 10% from 55% to 45%.  This is still far from the lab's climate most of the year.  It is a trade off, though, because it will also raise the lab temperature by about 1 degree C, which necessitates other recalibration.  I am investigating options to further reduce the humidity.

The lab is approximately   5 meters X 10 meters X 3 meters in size.  Most of the experiment is on a very full optics table that is 1.5 meters X 4 meters.  There are lots of cables and water tubing that require access to the table, making climate isolation of the table difficult (although not impossible).

A few options under consideration are the following:

**1:** Introduce an additional higher capacity dehumidifier

Pros:

- Fast and easy implementation

Cons:

- it is unknown how efficient a dehumidifier will function when the relative humidity is only 45%.
- Manufacturers do not specify how well the unit will work at low humidity levels, only at 80% +.

**2:** Fill sensitive areas with positive pressure Nitrogen

Pros:

- Excellent climate control
- Minimal impact on room temperature

Cons:

- requires significant reconfiguration of experimental setup.
- Requires refilling Nitrogen tank frequently, a recurring cost.

**3:** Isolate experiment from lab climate using large plastic enclosures and recirculate air in this enclosure

Pros:

- Excellent environment isolation

Cons:

- requires significant reconfiguration of laboratory and would likely restrict access to areas of the experiment.
- It could also likely result in a temperature increase of the experiment area.

Introducing an additional room dehumidifier would be the easiest option by far.

**So my Question is:** does anyone know how efficient dehumidifiers works in dry environments?  E.g., if I were to purchase an additional dehumidifier, would could I achieve a humidity level of less than 30% or does the humidity level asymptote off at some level due to a limit on the efficiency of dehumidifiers?

I realize an alternative would be to *humidify* the lab 10 months out of the year.  However, having low humidity is extremely convenient for rapidly water-cooling components.  During our wet season, our water-cooling results in considerable condensation on our components.

Comment: Chalk up to the list of Nitrogen's cons: danger to life and limb in case of a leak.

Comment: Joe - check out Chapter 23 of ASHRAE's HVAC Systems and Equipment Handbook (2008).

Comment: I found an interesting external link: Desiccant Dehumidification vs. Mechanical Refrigeration ( http://www.bry-air.com/desiccant-dehumidification-vs-mechanical-refrigeration.html )  In summary, their recommendation is that desiccant based dehumidifiers are necessary if you need relative humidity levels between 1% and 45%

Comment: Maybe you could use slightly warmer cooling water to prevent condensation?  Are you using open-cycle cooling - slightly wasteful.

Answer (score 1):

One option: Buy more dehumidifiers, and a space heater. Use the space heater to maintain the lab at the "elevated" temperature when the humidity is low and the dehumidifiers are not running.

Another option: Run your dehumidifier when the humidity is high, but run a humidifier when the humidity is low.  Meet in the middle.

Yet another option: Build a tent around your optics table and control the climate in there. Less air volume means less challenge.  The tent probably doesn't have to be completely airtight.

Answer (score 0):

It is probably not an answer good enough, but I try. My experiences with a small commercial dehumidifier were great when humidity was 100%. I tested it long term at 60% without big effect.

I was trying to decrease humidity with Calcium Chloride type material and ventilator (Silica gel is probably safer but less efficient), it worked better but 10%, I have never seen. But maybe with a lot of material...
  Actually I am impressed that you have 10%, even your presence must influence it...